# Why does Databricks get bottlenecked on single-threaded activity in their "driver daemon"?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

Databricks uses a "driver daemon" is a proprietary wrapper around the underlying implementation of OSS Spark.  This daemon is opaque and difficult to troubleshoot.

I'm attempting to use an all purpose cluster to perform a series of independent "jar tasks" in parallel.  I allow a number of concurrent tasks to run at a time (10 or more) and they are not intended to be synchronized or serialized in any way.  They are independent.

However as I scale up the workload, I find that I hit a bottleneck on single-threaded CPU activity within the driver.  The limit that is reached is well below max CPU available on the driver node.  It appears to be about ~25% of the CPU.

See the screenshot below.  It contains the CPU usage of the driver node.  Regardless of whether I attempt to run 20, 10, or 30 concurrent jobs (respectively), the CPU won't grow above ~25%.

[image]

If anyone understands how a databricks "driver daemon" works, can you please help me with one primary question:

What is the resource that is being synchronized/serialized in the driver daemon?  I'm assuming there is a resource bottleneck (critical section) rather than a deliberate attempt to serialize all the submitted jobs.

I realize that Databricks is supposed to be a high performing Spark platform.  In light of that, this bottleneck is surprising to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey David, Any update on this? We same architecture, trying to execute 25 jobs parallel using singelNode but it looks like its not utilizing CPU capacity fully.  

Did you found any workaround?